# UINavigationBar collapses automatically when contentInset is set

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout, safearealayoutguide

I've made simple project with single view controller inside `UINavigationController`. In the view controller I've added `UITableView` and set `contentInset.top = 52`.

When I push some view controller in navigation stack and pop back, large navigation bar collapses as shown on image below.

But if I don't set `contentInset`, that everything works correctly.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should activate Safe Area Relative Margins and Safe Area Layout Guide:
[image: Layout Margins]

Also in interface builder pin table view to Superview instead of Safe Area:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to setup prefersLargeTitles = true

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
```

Also, you don't want to show a large title in view detailViewControl, you can set up largeTitleDisplayMode = .never

```
navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
```